# How to align material-ui icon inside a button properly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

How do I align the `<ChevronRightIcon>` inside `<PrimaryButton>` properly. I want it after the button label towards the right.

[image: Screenshot]

```
<PrimaryButton style={{
                paddingRight: '26px'
                }} 
                label="Open Button"
                aria-controls="simple-menu"
                aria-haspopup="true"
                onClick={this.handleOpenMenu.bind(this)
                }
                className={classes.progress}
                color="#fff"
                >
                   <ChevronRightIcon></ChevronRightIcon>
 </PrimaryButton>
```

`<ChevronRightIcon>` is from material-ui and `<PrimaryButton>` is self created.

```
import React from 'react';
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';
export default function PrimaryButton(props) {
  const style = {
    height: 36,
    boxShadow: 'none',
    ...props.style,
  };
  return (
    <RaisedButton {...props} primary style={style} name="primary-button">
      {props.children}
    </RaisedButton>
  )
}

PrimaryButton.muiName = 'RaisedButton';
```

Comment: The easiest solution would probably to use the Material-UI Button class. See: [Button - Buttons with icons and label](https://material-ui.com/components/buttons/#buttons-with-icons-and-label) I'm guessing you are currently using your own component, since `PrimaryButton` is not defined by Material-UI. Without knowing the contents of `PrimaryButton` it is impossible to help you with a custom layout.

Comment: I'll add the PrimaryButton code for the reference in question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use an icon in a regular button you should pass your icon to `startIcon` or `endIcon` prop (in your case `endIcon`) [documentation](https://material-ui.com/api/button/). Then don't forget to pass all the passed props of your `PrimaryButton` to your `<Button/>` component.

```
<PrimaryButton
  endIcon={<ChevronRightIcon />}
  style={{
    paddingRight: '26px',
  }}
  label="Open Button"
  aria-controls="simple-menu"
  aria-haspopup="true"
  onClick={this.handleOpenMenu.bind(this)}
  className={classes.progress}
  color="#fff"
/>
```

```js
// import ChevronRightIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ChevronRight';
const icon = (name) => (props) => <MaterialUI.Icon {...props} children={name} />;
const ChevronRightIcon = icon("chevron_right");

function Demo() {
  return (
    <PrimaryButton
      endIcon={<ChevronRightIcon />}
      label="Open Button"
      variant="contained"
      // ...
    />
  );
}

function PrimaryButton({label, ...props}) {
  return (
    <MaterialUI.Button
      {...props}
      color="primary"
      children={label}
    />
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Demo />, document.querySelector("#demo"));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" />
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/@material-ui/core@4/umd/material-ui.development.js"></script>
<div id="demo"></div>
```